# Separate hashtags from string and store in separate rows

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to split my hashtags from a string from a single post so if there is more than one in a post they're separated into single `#hashtags` and put into separate rows in my hashtag table by their `post_id`.

Currently with my below function they're inserted into a single row and listed with a comma. How can I put them into an array and then store them individually, please?

Here is what I've tried to no avail:

```
      $hashtags ="#hashtag1 this is my string with two hashtags #hashtag2";
        if($hashtags==""){
                      }else{      
            function getHashtagsd($hashtags) {  
        $hashtagarray = FALSE;  
        preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/u", $hashtags, $matches);  
        if ($matches) {
            $hashtagarray = implode(",", $matches[0]);
        }
        return $hashtagarray;
    }

    $hashtagarray = getHashtagsd($hashtags);
$hashtagarray = getHashtagsd($hashtags);
$myArray1 = explode(';', $hashtagarray);
$myArray  = explode('#', $myArray1);

        $insertf = "INSERT INTO streamdata_hashtags(streamitem_hashtag_id,hashtag,streamitem_hashtag_timestamp) VALUES ($last_id,'$hashtagarray',NOW())";
                      $add_postf = mysqli_query($mysqli,$insertf) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        }
```

I added the explodes and got this error:

> explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

Comment: Let me re-write this thing and I'll get back to you with an answer.

Comment: Thank you @icecub your efforts are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a lot of coding that wasn't nessesary. I've updated the code and added some comments on how it works:

```
$hashtags = "#hashtag1 this is my string with two hashtags #hashtag2";

function getHashtagsd($hashtags) {
    preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/u", $hashtags, $matches);

    if ($matches) {
        return $matches[0]; // No need to implode, just return the array
    }
}

$hashtagarray = getHashtagsd($hashtags);

// Walk through the array and insert each hashtag
for($i = 0; $i < count($hashtagarray); $i++){
    $insertf = "INSERT INTO streamdata_hashtags(streamitem_hashtag_id,hashtag,streamitem_hashtag_timestamp) VALUES ($last_id,'". $hashtagarray[$i] ."',NOW())";
    $add_postf = mysqli_query($mysqli,$insertf) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic @icecub it works perfectly. Thank you so, so much.

Comment: @Gateway No worries. I do hope you will read and learn about Prepared Statements. Because like this, you are vulnerable to SQL Injection. This basicly means that pretty much any idiot can just destroy your entire database or give themselves an admin account etc etc

Comment: My string was sent through a function from another page within a `mysqli_real_escape_string`. But I plan to move to prepared statements in the near future. Thanks so much. And your profile description was a great read. Glad you can help others and will also do the same where I can.